# Can't import pip installed modules on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I'm a linux newbie that kind of screwed up the way python3 is set up in my server. It already had python 3.5 but I needed 3.6, so I installed it and now it won't import any modules that I install with pip3, one of my guesses is that the config of the system variables is wrong and python 3.6 can't access the libraries.

Sorry if it seems kind of vague, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.6 has its own sub-directory for packages; you'll need to reinstall all the packages.

This simply keeps the different Python versions separate from each other, and ensures no compatibility problems. For example, a package may be compatible with Python 3.6, but not with 3.5, and if you use both 3.5 and 3.6 (e.g., for testing purposes), the package wouldn't work for Python 3.5.

To differentiate between `pip` for Python 3.5 and that for 3.6, use it in its "module" command form:

```
python3.6 -m pip install <whatever>
```

and similar for `python3.5` or even `python2.7`(*)

---

One potentially simply way to install all your current Python 3.5 packages for Python 3.6 is with pip's `freeze` command and using `xargs`:

```
python3.5 -m pip freeze | xargs -n1 python3.6 -m pip install
```

The `-n1` feeds the list of packages one by one to `pip install`, so if there's a problem with a package upon installation for Python 3.6, you'll see an error message, but otherwise it'll happily keep going to the next package.

Note that `pip freeze` sticks to the *currently installed version* for each version; you won't automatically install the most recent version for Python 3.6 this way. Perhaps that is what you want. Otherwise, use the `--upgrade` flag:

```
python3.5 -m pip freeze | sed -ne 's/==.*//p' | xargs -n1 python3.6 -m pip install`
```

(This is also a way to upgrade all pip-installed packages in one go:

```
python -m pip freeze | sed -ne 's/==.*//p' | xargs -n1 python -m pip install --upgrade`
```

)

---

(*) if Python 2.7 is somewhat old, it may not have `pip` installed as a module by default.